# Android: App jumping from one activity to second without any action on first activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a basic feedback app in which the main activity (`MainActivity.java`) records the name of the customer and the rating (1-5) in the form of imageViews and sends the data to firebase.

My second activity (`Score.java`) simply aggregates the ratings from all the customers in firebase.

My issue is the app on startup directly jumps to `Score.java` without collecting the feedback from the customer. P.s. I am using `Intent` to jump between the activities.

Here is the code:

MainActivity-

```
package com.example.feedback;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;    
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import static android.os.SystemClock.sleep;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name;
    ImageView oneStar, twoStar, threeStar, fourStar, fiveStar;
    Intent intent;
    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    public void displayScore() {
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Score.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name =  findViewById(R.id.editTextPersonName);
        oneStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        twoStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        threeStar = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        fourStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        fiveStar =  findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        oneStar.setTag(1);
        twoStar.setTag(2);
        threeStar.setTag(3);
        fourStar.setTag(4);
        fiveStar.setTag(5);

        oneStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (name.length() == 0){
                    name.setError("Please enter your full name.");
                }
                else {
                    name.setError(null);
                    rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    reference = rootNode.getReference().child("Users");
                    //Fetch all values
                    String username = name.getText().toString();
                    String value = view.getTag().toString();
                    int rating = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    UserHelper helper = new UserHelper(username,rating);
                    reference.child(username).setValue(helper);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Feedback submitted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sleep(200);
                    displayScore();
                }
            }
        });

        twoStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (name.length() == 0){
                    name.setError("Please enter your full name.");
                }
                else {
                    name.setError(null);
                    rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    reference = rootNode.getReference().child("Users");
                    //Fetch all values
                    String username = name.getText().toString();
                    String value = view.getTag().toString();
                    int rating = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    UserHelper helper = new UserHelper(username,rating);
                    reference.child(username).setValue(helper);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Feedback submitted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    displayScore();
                }
            }
        });

        threeStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (name.length() == 0){
                    name.setError("Please enter your full name.");
                }
                else {
                    name.setError(null);
                    rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    reference = rootNode.getReference().child("Users");
                    //Fetch all values
                    String username = name.getText().toString();
                    String value = view.getTag().toString();
                    int rating = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    UserHelper helper = new UserHelper(username,rating);
                    reference.child(username).setValue(helper);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Feedback submitted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    displayScore();
                }
            }
        });

        fourStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (name.length() == 0){
                    name.setError("Please enter your full name.");
                }
                else {
                    name.setError(null);
                    rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    reference = rootNode.getReference().child("Users");
                    //Fetch all values
                    String username = name.getText().toString();
                    String value = view.getTag().toString();
                    int rating = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    UserHelper helper = new UserHelper(username,rating);
                    reference.child(username).setValue(helper);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Feedback submitted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    displayScore();
                }
            }
        });

        fiveStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (name.length() == 0){
                    name.setError("Please enter your full name.");
                }
                else {
                    name.setError(null);
                    rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    reference = rootNode.getReference().child("Users");
                    //Fetch all values
                    String username = name.getText().toString();
                    String value = view.getTag().toString();
                    int rating = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    UserHelper helper = new UserHelper(username,rating);
                    reference.child(username).setValue(helper);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Feedback submitted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    displayScore();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Score.java -

```
package com.example.feedback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Score extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView avgScore;
    DatabaseReference dbRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
        setContentView(R.layout.score);
        avgScore = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        scoreRealTime();
    }

    public void scoreRealTime() {
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                double total = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    double values = Double.parseDouble(ds.child("rating").getValue().toString());
                    total = total + values;
                }
                double average = (double) total / snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                avgScore.setText(String.format("%.2f", average));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.feedback">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Score"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm assuming there is something very simple, wrong with `displayScore()` but can't seem to figure it out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update your question with AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: There is a lot of repetition in your OnClickListener code. try extending View.OnclickListener and using it for all your buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have kept `Score` Activity as launcher activity. So use `MainActivity` as Launcher activity like this

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Score"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And one more suggestion there is a lot of code duplication you can make a function to upload rating and call it in else block of `onClickListner`

Comment: Ahh yes knew it was a silly mistake. It's working now.
Also, its jumping to Score.java without showing the Toast. Could you also help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

You have kept the second activity as the launcher activity, that is why android overlooks your MainActivity.java

You should change your Manifest as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Score"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and there can be one more improvement in your app, you can add recyclerView instead of 5 buttons, That will make your code shorter.

Comment: Yeah it's working now thanks. Also, the toast is not working before jumping to score.java. Could you also help me with that? And I haven't got much time to look into recyclerview but will definitely do.

Comment: Ok ask a seperate question for that and post the link here in comment and mention me. As this question is answered so there is no use of adding recyclerView answers here as people will find it different and not relatable!

Comment: Yes for the Toast you should remove all the toast from clickListners and probably add only one toast in displayScore() function